# Example of creating a model, subscribing and publishing its data to the client (Meteor)

Tags: meteor

I have a background in Rails and MVC frameworks, so I don't fully understand the idea of creating a model, publishing data and let the user subscribe to it.

I've been checking [Meteor's docs](http://docs.meteor.com/), but I'm still confused about some things (e.g. in which file the subscribe and publish declarations are supposed to go? In which file the template declarations are supposed to go?)

I'll be glad if someone could give me a workable example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
// Server publish the data
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("allUserData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  });
}

// Client subscribe the data
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('allUserData');
}

// Open bar, everybody can call all mongodb request
Meteor.users.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  update: function () {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (by the way, how to put that data into a template?)

Comment: if  I create an `User` collection, I have to replace `Meteor users` to `Users`?

Comment: you should read the doc and the examples, it shows how to access Users and put data in template

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start would be Meteor's own example apps. You can preview them (and get instructions on how to install them on you local machine) from the [examples page](http://meteor.com/examples/).

If you want to browse through some code check out their Gitgub repos. The [All Tomorrow's Parties](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/parties) demo is a fairly well rounded example which shows user auth, selective publishing, client and server code, etc.

Have a look at the [leaderboard demo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/leaderboard) for a very simple "hello world" type of example.

Comment: I checked the leaderboard example but it doesn't use subscribe or publish. The parties example is just too complex. I just want a simple example of defining a model, publish it and enable the client to subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
meteor create --example parties
```

and browse the code.
the thing is when you do: publish what you return is accessible as the model.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be oldest, but just to keep on the good practices.

First on the `/lib` folder create some `Collections.js`

And also make sure you remove Autopublish Package and insecure.
and inside the `Collection.js` puts the next code.

```
Example = new Mongo.Collection('Example');

    if(Meteor.isClient) {
     Meteor.subscribe('Example');
    }
```

Why on the `lib` folder ?

Because Files in the lib directory would be loaded first, so with that we make sure we have the collections on both, `Server/client` side

Now on the Server side we make the publish function.

```
 //Server.js
    Meteor.publish("Promociones", function () {
        return Example.find();
    });
```

I made this answer again since i realize i was using

```
Example = new Mongo.Collection('Example'); //on both server.js and client.js
```

So i think this is a Good practice and a good advice for newcomers